# AnonymousEndpoint When send email in WSO2 ESB

Tags: email, wso2, esb, endpoint, wso2-esb

When I Try a service which send message to an email, It send 1 message each 30sec 3 or 4 times. The error message is:

> Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint - last suspend duration was :
>   30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms

Why endpoint is marked like anonumousEndpoint if the message arrive to receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is adding this line before :

```
<header name="To" action="remove"></header>  
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
```